# Use pkgsrc and pkgin utilities from SmartOS on OmniOS

Tags: solaris, smartos, omnios

I am working with a virtual machine running 64 bit OmniOS install of solaris and would like to access packages in the joyent SmartOS package repository, I am trying to install pkgrsrc but have had not any luck.  I have tried following these instructions:
-http://pkgsrc.joyent.com/installing.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

So as it turns out Jonathan Perkin provides an excellent solution to this problem at:
http://www.perkin.org.uk/pages/pkgsrc-binary-packages-for-illumos.html

I had to run:

```
curl -s http://pkgsrc.joyent.com/packages/SmartOS/bootstrap/bootstrap-2013Q3-x86_64.tar.gz | gzcat | (cd /; sudo tar -xpf -)
```

Then I added: `PATH=/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:$PATH` to my .bashrc file

It works great now!